# Is there a way to fetch value of the column that was matched in where?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to develop a search algorithm. This is a problem I am facing right now.

| name | Location |
| --- | --- |
| First | location 1 |
| Second | location 2 |

Sql = select id, [matched_column_value] FROM table WHERE name = "%fir%" OR Location = "%fir%";

I want the value "First" in the matched_column_value.

If location column is matched the value should be of Location.

if anyone knows a function or method to solve this please let me know.

Comment: What if both match?

Comment: If both are matched any of them is okay

Comment: Can be done using `IF()`, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not exist a simple way. The ugly way could be something like this

```
SELECT id,
    CASE
        WHEN name LIKE "%fir%" and location LIKE "%fir%" THEN "???"
        WHEN name LIKE "%fir%" THEN name
        WHEN location LIKE "%fir%" THEN location
        ELSE null
    END as match
FROM 
    table
WHERE 
    name LIKE "%fir%" OR Location LIKE "%fir%";
```